# Apache Echarts YAxis ticks not visible when XAxis value is below zero

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, echarts

I'm facing an issue with Apache Echarts where the YAxis ticks are not visible when the XAxis value is below zero. A dark line is visible at the XAxis value 0 with axis ticks, which is also not expected.

I have tried adjusting the interval property of the axisLabel option for the YAxis and setting containLabel to true in the grid option, but none of these solutions have worked.

I have created a minimal example on the Apache Echarts official website to reproduce the issue. You can find it here: [Reproduction Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-in-cartesian-coordinate-system&lang=ts&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurALYTREC0AjAAwkC-ANCQJ475FKsl4BTAE4QBhWAG0S6VKVIATAIZhFRKXLkS69FrAAs9ALpsNpCQFYdsBkZOnJB3QCYj00sbfow7EAKIByABtKAX83JhJDFCYAbiA)

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to make the YAxis ticks visible when the XAxis value is below zero in Apache Echarts.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want the yAxis displayed on the left border of your plot and not on 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly and you are bothered that the [`axisLine`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.axisLine) of your yAxis is on zero, you just need to set `axisLine: {onZero: false}`.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-in-cartesian-coordinate-system&lang=ts&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurALYTREC0AjAAwkC-ANCQJ475FICGueADKUApjxgAtEQCdgRAGa8ANnhFNWJVdIgjCsANol0qUqQAmvMLyKHTp_XXotYAFnoBdNndL6ArE9gGDy9vAzdnACYPI1JPGPQwdhAxWAByJVFUmKYSdxQmAG4gA) is your adjusted example:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    min: -10
  },
  yAxis: { axisLine: { onZero: false } },
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        [-10, 40],
        [50, 100],
        [40, 20]
      ],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};
```